# How to pass my previous n variables in for loop recursive function?

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a `for`-loop recursive function and I want to access the previous `n` variables. How do I go about doing it?

```
function Signal(arr,val)


    recu=length([arr 1]);

    if recu==1
        return
    end

    for n=1:1:3-val
       n

       %%// now I want to save all my Previous n variables to pass to the next  for loop%

       val=n;
       Signal(arr(1:1:end-1),val)

    end

end
```

Comment: I don't understand what your function is supposed to do, but a return value is missing: `function r=Signal(arr,val)` for example

Comment: i want to pass all the n variables from the previous for loop  to the next for loop

Comment: what stops you then? :)

Comment: What's stopping me?
Actually nothing.

Comment: What is the goal of you function? What is it supposed to do (bigger picture)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion can be useful when the problem can be solved by dividing it into smaller instances of the same problem. For example the fibonacci sequence where the n:th number is the sum of the two previous numbers, **fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)**. This means you can calculate the n:th number by calling the same function on the previous two numbers.

```
function y = fib(n)

if (n==0 || n==1)
    y=1;
else
    y = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
end

end
```

Note here that the function is completely ignorant about what happened in the previous recursion. Also, note that a recursive function in Matlab need a return value since Matlab always is pass-by-value. This particular example can of course be solved with an iterative approach much more efficiently, but it is usually used for educational purposed due to its obvious recursive connection. Another example is quicksort (useful, look it up!) which in an efficient way sorts subarrays.

Your problem requires information from previous calls, which does not make it suitable for recursion. In case you really need to solve it like this, you must pass all information you need as parameters. There is no other way to provide a function with information (global variables could used though, but it unpleasant in many ways and not recommended). In case you feel you have too many parameters you can pass them as a struct instead. A good struct name can make the function more pleasant to look at and easier to read.